# Why the generating function of $\frac{2^K}{k!}$ is $e^{2x}$ instead of $e^{2^{x}}$?

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

I'm trying to find the generating function of $\frac{2^k}{k!}$, as there is a $k!$ in the denominator, it must be related to $e^x$, then perhaps, just a simple substitution is needed.

The sequence given by $a_k=\frac{2^k}{k!}$ is $\left\{1,2,2,\frac{4}{3},\frac{2}{3},\frac{4}{15},\frac{4}{45},\frac{8}{315},\frac{2}{315},\frac{4}{2835},\frac{4}{14175}\right\}$, the generating functions I proposed are:

$$e^{2x}=\ldots + \frac{4 x^6}{45}+\frac{4 x^5}{15}+\frac{2 x^4}{3}+\frac{4 x^3}{3}+2 x^2+2 x+1$$

$$e^{2^{x}}=\ldots + 2^x+2^{2 x-1}+\frac{1}{3} 2^{3 x-1}+\frac{1}{3} 2^{4 x-3}+\frac{1}{15} 2^{5
   x-3}+\frac{1}{45} 2^{6 x-4}+1$$

I know that the coefficients of $e^{2x}$ are exactly the ones in the sequence of $a_k$ and this would show the answer. The problem is that I spent some time thinking about it, I looked at the answers in the back of the book and the generating function was actually $e^{2x}$. I have the answer, but I don't fully understand what's happening.

**EDIT**: My problem is that using $2x$ is just like a lucky guess. It could be anything, is there any systematic method that shows precisely that $y$ must be $2x$?

Comment: Generating function = powers-series. The last series is not a power-series (yet). And if you make it into one, then it does not have the correct form.

Comment: I don't really understand the question; you had an idea and checked that it was right. I presume you wrote down the general formula for the coefficients rather than just computing the first few terms?

Comment: @Hurkyl Take a look at the edit I made.

Comment: @Winther Yes, but instead of $2x$, it could be other thing that would still give me a power series. I'm curious about some sistematic way to show that it *needs* to be $2x$. Using $2x$ is just like a *lucky guess*, I'm curious about a method that shows that only $2x$ would work.

Comment: We have $e^y = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{y^k}{k!}$. We want $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k x^k = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{2^kx^k}{k!}$. Solve to find $y=2x$!

Comment: @Winther That was exactly what I was looking for. You should put it as an answer instead. In my course, we still didn't have a good training in sums, I'll have to study it alone in Knuth's Concrete Mathematics. That's the maing reason I couldn't guess that an equality of sums would solve it.

Comment: If $f(x)$ is the generating function of $a_n$, then $f(cx)$ is the generating function of $c^na_n$, no? In your case, $c=2$. So the problem is reduced to finding the generating function of $\frac1{n!}$. With not too much effort, one realizes that the generating function $f$ of $\frac1{n!}$ satisfies $f'(x)=f(x)$ and $f(0)=1$, and you have $f(x)=e^x$.

Answer (score 1):

I may be pointing out the obvious, but...

Set $y=2x$. Then
$$
1+y+\frac{y^2}{2!}+\frac{y^3}{3!}+\dots = 1+2x+\frac{(2x)^2}{2!}+\frac{2x^3}{3!}+\dots = 1+2x+\frac{2^2}{2!}x^2+\frac{2^3}{3!}x^3+\dots
$$

Set $z=2^x$. Then,
$$
1+z+\frac{z^2}{2}+\frac{z^3}{3!}+\dots = 1+2^x+\frac{2^{2x}}{2!}+\frac{2^{3x}}{3!}+\dots
$$
It is possible to use $2^x=e^{x\log 2}$ to transform this further into an ordinary power series, but I think that from these substitutions you can already see why things aren't turning out as you expected.

Comment: Yes. But my problem is that using $y=2x$ is just like a lucky guess. It could be anything, is there any systematic method that shows precisely that $y$ must be $2x$?

Comment: The first time you see it looks like a lucky guess, indeed. Then you realize that a substitution of the form $y=ax$ always produces an additional factor $a^k$ in the expression for the general coefficient; so whenever you can write a power series for a sequence $c_k$ you can write one for $c_k a^k$, too. I think it was Polya who said "a standard method is just a clever trick that happens to work on many problems". :)

Comment: Winther also pointed something very interesting in the comments. Take a look.

Comment: @Vÿska "Solve for x" is a bit unclear, and it hides an important detail (that it is not a requirement that the two sums have to match summand-by-summand), but overall I like the method, too; it looks more intuitive in this case.