# How to identify which terms are infinite sequences?

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

I've made [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1093568/25805) some time ago. I thought that the term $x$ in $x+e^x$ would be a sequence $a_x=x=\{0,1,2,3,\ldots\}$ and it turns out that it is the sequence $\{0,1,0,0,\ldots\}$.

Whenever I see an exercise now, I assume that $x$ has the sequence I pointed, and when I see $x^2$, I assume the sequence as $\{0,0,1,0,\ldots\}$. The problem is that I'm not really sure why that is so, I just saw some examples and copied without really understanding it. My guess is that it has something to do with [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1093568/why-the-sequence-generated-by-xex-is-1-x-fracx22-fracx33-fr#comment2229582_1093580) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1091625/why-the-generating-function-of-frac2kk-is-e2x-instead-of-e2x#comment2224975_1091625).

Does the summation method pointed in these comments indicate a way of discovering it? I am having a introduction to combinatorial analysis and we didn't have a thorough training in summations, nor training in series (I'm currently reading Knuth/Graham/Patashnik to suplement this). But I'd like to have a brief direction of how to discover this.

Comment: That old question and this one are both a bit of a mess. It would be good up front to mention here that you are talking about generating functions, but you seem to be using a very odd notation for generating functions.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Could you suggest something better? I'm just speaking about it as I looked in the book.

Answer (score 1):

To determine if a sequence goes on forever, you can use ellipses such as in {$\cdots-2, -1, 0, 1, 2\cdots$} showing that they do that, like you did.  It can also be identified by when something says "all integers", "all even numbers greater than $-5$", "all numbers divisible by $10$", etc.  The word "all" identifies that any of those sequences goes on forever meaning it doesn't have a finite number of numbers in it just for the ones I showed you and ones that have the same thing.